# How do I get the ID value from facebook JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, facebook-graph-api

basically, I have input where you type the facebook user ID and and then the script fetches its value to get the link to facebook graph like:

```
var faceuserID = document.getElementById('userID').value;
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/' + faceuserID, function(data) {

}
```

Then I can get the link to the facebook graph which returns the JSON array. However I need only the ID value to some new variable. How do I get it?

Comment: `var faceuserID = document.getElementById('userID').value;` can be shorten to `var faceuserID = $('#userID').val();`

Comment: What 'ID value' you need?

Comment: When i get the link e.g. http://graph.facebook.com/zuck the JSON has the data of facebook unique user id which in this example is 4. That's the number i want to get to variable

Answer (score 0):

You have to you  [attr(jquery)](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). ID is attribute, not a value.